# Combine 2 table

Tags: mysql

when I have table status like below

```
id  | status    | prev_status
 1  | open      | 0
 2  | checking  | 1
 3  | reject    | 2
 4  | approve   | 2
 5  | close     | 4
```

and a table transaction below

```
id  | no     |   date     | status_id
 1  |  IDN01 | 2018-12-01 |  1
 2  |  IDN02 | 2018-12-02 |  2
 3  |  IDN03 | 2018-12-03 |  1
 4  |  IDN04 | 2018-12-04 |  1
 5  |  IDN05 | 2018-12-05 |  4
```

When I do `SELECT status_id FROM transaction WHERE id = 2` How to show result show the next status also for status_id in id 2

```
status_id | status 
    2     | checking
    3     | reject
    4     | approve
```

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: are you trying to view next status or previous ??  i think it is obvious that open status is fowled by checking then either approve or reject then close

Comment: What is your question exactly? Read [ask] and create a [mcve] (example that actually make sense)

Comment: I want to view current status and next status

Comment: Which _next status_?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database model is kind of weird having those two separate foreign keys. Anyway, the query you may be looking for is:

```
select c.id, c.status
from transaction t
join status c on c.id = t.status_id
where t.id = 2
union all
select p.id, p.status
from transaction t
join status p on p.prev_status = t.status_id
where t.id = 2
```